# Detect if custom UITextField has a text value

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I created a custom text field, a class that extends a UITextField, how can I know if that UITextField has a value, I already tried the `shouldChangeCharactersIn` but nothing happened.

This is my code for my custom UITextField Class

```swift
@IBDesignable class CustomTextField: UITextField {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        loadContent()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        loadContent()
    }
    ...
}
```

I want to print `"the textfield is blank"` if the UITextField is blank or if the user removed the value in it, and `"the textfield has content"` if there's a value in it or if the user add a value in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a target to your text field for  `UIControl.Event` `.editingChanged`

```
override func willMove(toSuperview newSuperview: UIView?) {
    addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingChanged), for: .editingChanged)
}
```

And use `UIKeyInput` method `hasText` to check if your field is empty or not:

```
@objc func editingChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
    print("the textfield " + (hasText ? "has content" : "is blank"))
}
```

Comment: I tried adding the `addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingChanged), for: .editingChanged)` inside `override init(frame: CGRect)` but it doesn't print anything whenever I add or removed the text in the textfield

Comment: I would override willMoveToSuperview instead of overriding its init method

Comment: willMove(toSuperview newSuperview: UIView?) worked for me